# Strange behaviour when breakpoint in visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2005, breakpoints

I have to maintain a C# project built in VS 2005 (.NET 2.0), but when I put a breakpoint in specific line during debug, something strange happens:

[image: Before breakpoint]

[image: After breakpoint]

I have found that Resharper could cause those kind of "problems", but its licence has been expired from more than six months.

Comment: Option 1 turn off/uninstall resharper. Option 2 renew license.

Comment: i would try the universal hack to all IT problems first ie Restarting you vs

Comment: @Muds I tried to restart pc. Nothing changes.

Comment: @Reniuz I suspended Resharper activation through the "Tools" menu, in fact I do not see Resharper menu bar anymore. Do I have to make something stronger (erase some windows registry keys)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue uninstalling completely resharper from my laptop.
Here is the reference link (for me, point 2 worked):

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545359-Uninstalling-ReSharper-Ultimate-tools-from-Visual-Studio

> To completely remove ReSharper Ultimate tools from Visual Studio,
>   please try the following:
>
> 1. Run ReSharper Ultimate installer once again - do you have any products with status Repair? If so, please select Remove for them and
>      select Skip for others.
> 2. If there are no items with Repair action, please remove the following folder manually
>      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio{Visual Studio
>      version}\Extensions\JetBrains
> 3. If Visual Studio still thinks ReSharper is installed, try deleting the following Windows Registry branch
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio{VS version}_Config

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21874590)

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks. But was it necessary downvoting the answer?

Comment: I did not downvote the answer so I cannot tell you why it was downvoted